# How does "[*(p++) / 52]" in "putchar(" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]);" work?

Tags: arrays, c, string

Whenever I look up the "putchar()" function, I can't seem to find a source on how something like the expression in the title would work. This is from a FFMPEG API example for filtering/decoding.

Here's a link to the source: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering__video_8c.html

Lines 203 - 212

```
    puts("\033c");
    for (y = 0; y < frame->height; y++) {
        p = p0;
        for (x = 0; x < frame->width; x++)
            putchar(" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]);
        putchar('\n');
        p0 += frame->linesize[0];
    }
```

Comment: `putchar()` just prints the value passed via its argument.  If you can't figure out the argument then that has nothing in particular to do with `putchar()` or function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is array access combined with an array defenition.  `" .-+#"` is a string literal, which is a `char[]`.  The `[*(p++) / 52]` part is indexing into that array to access the element of the string literal at location of `*(p++) / 52`.

To sum it up, `" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]` is going to resolve to a single character from the string `" .-+#"`

Answer (score 3):

`" .-+#"` is a string literal of 6 characters (the last of which is a null character); with `" .-+#"[index]` you get one of those characters, as long as `index` is between `0` and `5`.

The way the index is calculated is based on the current value of `*p`, to which an integer division by `52` is applied. So, if `*p` is between 0 and 51, a space will be printed; if `*p` is between 52 and 103, a `.` will be printed and so on. The `++` increases `p` (the value that points to `*p`) for the next iteration (so going forward in the array) and does not affect the current expression.

So, if `p0` points to an array such as `[43, 78, 173, 145, 215]`, the string printed will be  `.+-#`

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `putchar`:

```
" .-+#"[*(p++) / 52]
```

Is the string constant `" .-+#"` with array subscripting applied to it.  So the expression `*(p++) / 52` apparently evaluated to a value between 0 and 4 which is used to select one of the characters in the string constant to print.

Comment: Of course, if they were really evil, they would have written it as `(*p++ / 52)[" .-+#"]`. :-)